# Determine with jQuery validator that the value entered is NOT a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, numbers

My problem is very simple, but I can't find an equally simple solution. I have a text field that is validated via the jQuery validation plugin, and I want to make sure that the value entered is NOT a number. What is the simplest way to do so?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't work with jQuery validator yet, but I guess you can provide your own validation function.

You could do:

```
if(isNaN(+value)) {
    // not a number
}
```

*Edit: Apparently, `isNaN` accepts a string too, so `isNaN(value)` suffices*.

If you want to ensure that the input does not contain any digit (which is different from the input not being a number), then you would have to use regular expressions:

```
if(!(/\d/.test(value))) {
    // does not contain digits
}
```

*P.S.: Also works without jQuery ;)*

Comment: You can pass a string straight into "isNaN()"; you don't need the "+" to make it a number first.